# Best Processor for MediaSmart Server?

Tags: cpu, upgrade, hp-mediasmart

I'm trying to figure out what the best possible processor is that I can stick in my HP MediaSmart server. I'm clueless when it comes to correlating CPUs to motherboards. I suspect it's the socket type I care about, but I worry that there's more to it.

CPU-Z gives me (excerpt):

```
Processors Information
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Processor 1         ID = 0
    Number of cores     1 (max 1)
    Number of threads   1 (max 1)
    Name            AMD Sempron LE-1150
    Codename        Sparta
    Specification       AMD Sempron(tm) Processor LE-1150
    Package         Socket AM2 (940)
    CPUID           F.F.1
    Extended CPUID      F.7F
    Brand ID        1
    Core Stepping       DH-G1
    Technology      65 nm
    Core Speed      1000.0 MHz
    Multiplier x FSB    5.0 x 200.0 MHz
    HT Link speed       800.0 MHz
    Stock frequency     2000 MHz
    Instructions sets   MMX (+), 3DNow! (+), SSE, SSE2, SSE3, x86-64
    L1 Data cache       64 KBytes, 2-way set associative, 64-byte line size
    L1 Instruction cache    64 KBytes, 2-way set associative, 64-byte line size
    L2 cache        256 KBytes, 16-way set associative, 64-byte line size
    FID/VID Control     yes
    Max FID         10.0x
    Max VID         1.350 V
    P-State         FID 0x2 - VID 0x12 (5.0x - 1.100 V)
    P-State         FID 0xA - VID 0x0C (9.0x - 1.250 V)
    P-State         FID 0xC - VID 0x0A (10.0x - 1.300 V)

    K8 Thermal sensor   yes
    K8 Revision ID      6.0
    Attached device     PCI device at bus 0, device 24, function 0
    Attached device     PCI device at bus 0, device 24, function 1
    Attached device     PCI device at bus 0, device 24, function 2
    Attached device     PCI device at bus 0, device 24, function 3

Chipset
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Northbridge         SiS 761GX rev. 02
Southbridge         SiS 966 rev. 59
Graphic Interface       AGP
AGP Revision            3.0
AGP Transfer Rate       8x
AGP SBA             supported, enabled
Memory Type         DDR2
Memory Size         2048 MBytes
Channels            Single
Memory Frequency        200.0 MHz (CPU/5)
CAS# latency (CL)       5.0
RAS# to CAS# delay (tRCD)   5
RAS# Precharge (tRP)        5
Cycle Time (tRAS)       15
Bank Cycle Time (tRC)       21
Command Rate (CR)       1T

DMI
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

DMI BIOS        
    vendor          Phoenix Technologies, LTD
    version         R03
    date            05/08/2008

DMI System Information      
    manufacturer        HP
    product         MediaSmart Server
    version         unknown
    serial          CN68330DGH
    UUID            A482007B-B0CC7593-DD11736A-407B7067

DMI Baseboard       
    vendor          Wistron
    model           SJD4
    revision        A.0
    serial          unknown

DMI System Enclosure        
    manufacturer        HP
    chassis type        Desktop
    chassis serial      unknown

DMI Processor       
    manufacturer        AMD
    model           AMD Sempron(tm) Processor LE-1150
    clock speed     2000.0 MHz
    FSB speed       200.0 MHz
    multiplier      10.0x

DMI Memory Controller       
    correction      64-bit ECC
    Max module size     4096 MBytes

DMI Memory Module       
    designation     A0
    size            2048 MBytes (double bank)

DMI Memory Module       
    designation     A1

DMI Memory Module       
    designation     A2

DMI Memory Module       
    designation     A3

DMI Port Connector      
    designation     PS/2 Mouse (internal)
    port type       Mouse Port
    connector       PS/2
    connector       PS/2

DMI Port Connector      
    designation     USB0 (external)
    port type       USB

DMI Physical Memory Array       
    location        Motherboard
    usage           System Memory
    correction      None
    max capacity        16384 MBytes
    max# of devices     4

DMI Memory Device       
    designation     A0
    format          DIMM
    type            unknown
    total width     64 bits
    data width      64 bits
    size            2048 MBytes

DMI Memory Device       
    designation     A1
    format          DIMM
    type            unknown
    total width     64 bits
    data width      64 bits

DMI Memory Device       
    designation     A2
    format          DIMM
    type            unknown
    total width     64 bits
    data width      64 bits

DMI Memory Device       
    designation     A3
    format          DIMM
    type            unknown
    total width     64 bits
    data width      64 bits
```

How do I figure out what options I have for an upgrade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Sempron LE 1150 that you have now is a socket AM2 processor.  It's designed for home theater or media PCs, in that it has decent performance while producing less heat and using less energy than some other conventional chips.

There aren't a whole lot of new socket AM2 chips available these days, as they aren't really manufactured anymore.  One is the LE-1250, which is basically the same as your processor but running at 2.2GHz rather than 2GHz.  It's available from [NewEgg](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819103717) for $36.

The newer socket AM2+ chips can plug into most AM2 motherboards (but not all, depending on manufacturer, mainly BIOS compatibility), but will only operate at the older HyperTransport 2.0 spec.

The possibility of AM2+ opens you up to much faster chips like the Phenom II X4 940 3GHz quad-core chip, available from [NewEgg](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819103644) for $96, if your motherboard can support it.  That CPU has 4 cores to your CPU's single core, and each core operates at 3GHz, 50% faster in clock speed than your CPU's 2GHz.  Additionally, the newer Phenom II architecture has its own benefits.  Note that a higher power chip may require more cooling and energy, and may lead to a louder system.

To see all your options, basically look for socket AM2 and AM2+ chips.

Comment: Thanks @phoebus. Just to clarify, are you saying that my motherboard supports AM2, but you're not certain whether it supports AM2+?

Comment: do you know what model of motherboard your server has in it?

Comment: @Kent that's correct, your motherboard has an AM2 socket, but most motherboards that support AM2 can also use AM2+ processors, albeit without utilizing the latest HyperTransport 3 speeds.  Most AM2 motherboards support AM2+ chips, I just didn't want to tell you that definitively since I know that occasionally AM2 MBs don't support AM2+ (mostly due to outdated/custom BIOSes).

Answer (score 1):

You could use an AMD Athlon 64 X2 5050e. it's a dual core 2.6Ghz 65nm chip. That would effectively more than double your processing power and it's architeture is good for power consumption and heat.

Answer (score 1):

This thread is a little old, but I have a question and a suggestion for you.

Suggestion first: I run an AMD Athlon 64 X2 4450e. It's 65nm and core voltage runs about 1.23 or 1.24. It's not too bad for heat and a lot faster than the original processor.

Question: I noticed your bios is R03. Mine is only R02. Do you know how to use winflash or some other utility to pull a backup of that bios? If you can, and could email it to me, I would like to compare the two versions.